# Encrypting with EasyRSA in PHP and Decrypting with Node-RSA in JS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption, cryptography

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a simple trustless file sharing application. I'm using EasyRSA (https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA) to create a key-pair and then encrypt my data with the public key. I'm sending the private key to my JS wherein I'm using Node-RSA (https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa). Here, I try to decrypt using the previously created private key. But this happens:

**Error**

```
Uncaught Error: Error during decryption (probably incorrect key). Original error: Error: Incorrect data or key
    at NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.$$decryptKey (drop.js:23265)
    at NodeRSA.module.exports.NodeRSA.decrypt (drop.js:23213)
    at window.onload (drop.js:22270)
```

My JS code looks something like this:

```
var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
window.onload = function() {
    var key_val = $('#key').val();
    var ciphertext = $('#encrypted').val();
    var key = new NodeRSA();
    key.importKey($('#key').val(), 'pkcs1');
    var ciphertext_base = key.encrypt(ciphertext, 'base64');
    var decrypted_base = key.decrypt(btoa(ciphertext));
    console.log(decrypted);

}
```

I think this has got something to do with the incompatibility between the formats/key-sizes/algos used to create the keys. If someone could help me 'hack' this and make it work, I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information...  PHP code?  What format are your keys in?  Give examples of input and output data etc.

Comment: For starters, EasyRSA doesn't use PKCS1 padding. For another, the actual encryption is [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption).